# ls -l without file permissions

Tags: command-line, ls

How can I use `ls` while using `-l` (long listing) without showing the file permissions?

[image: This is what I want displayed when executing <code>ls</code>]

Right now I have the following alias for `ls`:

`alias ls='ls -lhaG --color=auto'`

I have found [a solution](https://superuser.com/a/343881/513404) *close* to what I'm looking for, but it doesn't maintain the syntax colouring or spacing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ls -lhaG --color=always | sed -re 's/^[^ ]* //'`

`--color=always` makes `ls` always output colour ESC codes, even when piping to another program.

The `sed` script removes the first field (the permissions).

NOTE that if you have `$LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'` in the environment, then that will override the `--color=always` option on the command line.  In that case, run it like this:

`LS_OPTIONS= ls -lhaG --color=always | sed -re 's/^[^ ]* //'`

NOTE ALSO that you will probably regret making `ls` an alias for this as it will make it a PITA to redirect directory listings to a file or to pipe them into another program without getting the ESC colour codes in the output.  To see just how ugly this is, try `ls -lhaG --color=always | sed -re 's/^[^ ]* //'  | cat -A`

Comment: Thank you for that last note, I'll have to make a separate alias for this output.

Comment: @cas, The caveat, though, is that this substitution also kills hyperlinks if `ls` output does contain those.